# What is the worst time complexity of the following code?

Tags: time-complexity

What is the worst time complexity of the following code ?

The array stores non-repeated integer numbers. In every row, the numbers are stored from smallest to largest. Also, the numbers in row(i+1) are greater than the largest number in row i.

```js
let M = [[1,5,9,11],
         [13,17,19,22],
         [27,31,33,35],
         [37,39,41,43],
         [45,47,49,100]]



function Search_Matrix(M,low,high,x){
  let C = 4
  if(low<=high){
    mid = parseInt(low+(high-low)/2)
    console.log("mid="+mid)
    //console.log("M[mid][0]="+M[mid][0])
    if((M[mid][0]<=x) && (M[mid][C-1]>=x)) {
      return mid
    }else{
      if(M[mid][0]>x){
        return Search_Matrix(M,low,mid-1,x)
      }
      if(M[mid][C-1]<x){
        return Search_Matrix(M,mid+1,high,x)
      }
    }
  }else{
    return -1
  }
}

console.log(Search_Matrix(M,0,4,20))
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like 'Binary Search' and worst-case complicity should be Theta(logN)